# Android SDK Dialog Bug

Tags: php, android, dialog

I am working on a Login and Registration App. 
My problem is that the error alert shows if there is an error or the registration was successful. So I don't know where the mistake is.

CODE :

```
package test.test.com.test;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;


public class Registraition extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button b_login;
    Button b_register;
    RadioGroup gender;

    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    EditText first_name,last_name,email,pass,cpass;
    String birth,gender_value;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registraition);
        b_login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_go_login);

        b_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Registraition.this, MainActivity.class));
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }
        });
        b_register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_register);

        b_register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Registraition.this, "",
                        "Register user...", true);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        register();
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
    }

    void register () {
        try{
            first_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_firstname);
            last_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_lastname);
            pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_password);
            cpass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_cpassword);
            email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_email);
            birth = DatePickerFragment.date;
            gender = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.gender);
            int id = gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            if (id == R.id.radioButton_female){
                gender_value = "female";
            } else {
                gender_value = "male";
            }
            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.178.174/app/register.php"); 
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(7);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname",first_name.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname",last_name.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passwordconfirm",cpass.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("birth",birth.trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender",gender_value.trim()));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            System.out.println("Response : " + response);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){
                //Here the Mistacke begins
                Toast.makeText(Registraition.this,"Register Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(Registraition.this, MainActivity.class));
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }else {
                showAlert();
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            dialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

    public void showAlert(){
        Registraition.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Registraition.this);
                builder.setTitle("Registraition Error.");
                builder.setMessage("Error on Registraition")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: What error is showing up? Look inside the response object, what is there at the momen of OK registration

Comment: Only the Error Dialog from the showAlert Function. but he should open the main activity.

Comment: What is the value of the reponse variable?

Comment: The PHP dies on Success with the Value "Success";

Comment: The biggest mistacke is that he show the Error Alert but the user was registered.

Comment: PHP and you show us java code?

Comment: Yes because the Java Code to the Mistacke not the PHP Code. The PHP Code do the right but the Java Code opens the Error Dialog on success.

Comment: The PHP dies on Success, does not looks like it works on PHP side... As asked twice already, what is the content of the reponse valiable?

Answer (score 0):

This is the output:

```
07-26 14:58:52.326    1902-2286/test.test.com.test I/System.out﹕ Response : ERROR
07-26 14:58:52.447    1902-1929/test.test.com.test W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-26 14:58:52.447    1902-1929/test.test.com.test W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5ba7520, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

But the User was registered. The PHP Code was:

```
<?php require("../login/common.php");
    $message = '';
    $signup = "false";
    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 
        if(empty($_POST["firstname"]) or empty($_POST["lastname"]) or empty($_POST["password"]) or empty($_POST["passwordconfirm"]) or empty($_POST["birth"])) {
        die("ERROR");
    }
    elseif(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    { 
        die("ERROR");
    }
    elseif($_POST["password"] == $_POST["passwordconfirm"]) {
        $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
        $cpassword = test_input($_POST["passwordconfirm"]);
        if (strlen($_POST["password"]) <= '5') {
            die("Password to short(min. 6)");
        }
    }
    elseif(!empty($_POST["password"])) {
        die("ERROR");
    }
    $signup = "true";
    if($signup == "true") { 


        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                email = :email 
        "; 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
           //normaly die("ERROR") but this is one of the mistackes
        } 

        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        if($row) 
        { 
        } 

        $query = " 
            INSERT INTO users ( 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email,
                gender,
                birthday
            ) VALUES ( 
                :username, 
                :password, 
                :salt, 
                :email,
                :gender,
                :birthday
            ) 
        "; 
        $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 
        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
        }
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $birthday = $_POST['birth'];
        $username = $_POST['firstname'] . " " . $_POST['lastname'];
        $query_params = array(
            ':username' => $username, 
            ':password' => $password, 
            ':salt' => $salt, 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'],
            ':gender' => $gender,
            ':birthday' => $birthday
        ); 
        try 
        {
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        {  
           //normaly die("ERROR") but this is one of the mistackes
        }
        if($signup == "true") {
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            mkdir("C:/xampp/htdocs/Users/" . $_POST['email']);
            $src = "C:/xampp/htdocs/Users/Sample";
            $dst = "C:/xampp/htdocs/Users/" . $_POST['email'];
            xcopy($src,$dst);
            $savemodi = $_POST["savemodi"];
            if($savemodi == true) {
                $saveinfopath = "C:/xampp/htdocs/Users/" . $_POST['email'] . "/";
                $file = fopen($saveinfopath . $savemodi . "/infos.txt","w");
                $userinfos = fwrite($file,$username . "°" . $_POST['email'] . "°" . $gender . "°" . $birthday . "°" . $result['id']);
                fclose($file);
                $saveinfopath = "C:/xampp/htdocs/Users/" . $_POST['email'] . "/";
                $file = fopen($saveinfopath . "public/infos.txt","w");
                $userinfos = fwrite($file,$username . "°°°°" . $result['id']);
                fclose($file);
            } else {
                $saveinfopath = "C:/xampp/htdocs/Users/" . $_POST['email'] . "/";
                $file = fopen($saveinfopath . $savemodi . "/infos.txt","w");
                $userinfos = fwrite($file,$username . "°" . $_POST['email'] . "°" . $gender . "°" . $birthday . "°" . $result['id']);
                fclose($file);
                $saveinfopath = "C:/xampp/htdocs/Users/" . $_POST['email'] . "/";
                $file = fopen($saveinfopath . "private/infos.txt","w");
                $userinfos = fwrite($file,$username . "°" . $_POST['email'] . "°" . $gender . "°" . $birthday . "°" . $result['id']);
                fclose($file);
            }
        die("Success");
    } else {
      die("ERROR");
    }?>
```

So I mark the ERRORS in the PHP Code with a comment.